# Como fazer o Create event no MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, eventos

Estou aprendendo agora sobre o create event no mysql

Estou criando um event simples de teste, mas ele não está funcionando, ele aparece em Eventos, mas a tabela não é atualizada:

```
CREATE EVENT teste
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
    DO
      UPDATE euk_teste SET status=2 WHERE id_produto=1;
```

Está faltando alguma coisa? Preciso habilitar algo?

Answer (score 2):

A sintaxe está correta. Provavelmente o serviço de agendamento esteja parado.

**Consulta para verificar o status do serviço:**

```
SELECT @@EVENT_SCHEDULER;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ativando o serviço:**

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```